# Getting java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException for spark-submit job against Cassandra database

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to Spark/Cassandra.

Running Join sql on Spark with below command. Getting timeout error in 10 sec. Same is working some times. Not really sure what is the problem. Even passed Brodcasttimeout also high.

I am using Datastax 6.8

Please help.

```
-bash-4.2$ dse -u cassandra -p cassandra spark-submit --class com.datastax.spark.example.WriteRead  --executor-memory 10G --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 5  --driver-memory 20G test_cassandras3_new.py --master dse://10.41.48.78 --deploy-mode cluster
```

*Cassandra test job started

```
Monday, 01. June 2020 03:43:17AM Statement Number : 10

Monday, 01. June 2020 03:43:19AM Statement Number : 20

Monday, 01. June 2020 03:43:32AM Job failed at statement number 20 immediate action required An error occurred while calling o181.showString. : java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:411)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.SolrPredicateRules$$anonfun$19.apply(SolrPredicateRules.scala:371)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.SolrPredicateRules$$anonfun$19.apply(SolrPredicateRules.scala:361)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:115)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:114)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:158)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.SolrPredicateRules.convertToSolrQuery(SolrPredicateRules.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.SolrPredicateRules.apply(SolrPredicateRules.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.SolrPredicateRules.apply(SolrPredicateRules.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$$anonfun$predicatePushDown$1$$anonfun$20.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$$anonfun$predicatePushDown$1$$anonfun$20.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:289)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$$anonfun$predicatePushDown$1.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$$anonfun$predicatePushDown$1.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:269)
        at scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap.getOrElseUpdate(TrieMap.scala:901)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation.predicatePushDown(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation.unhandledFilters(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.selectFilters(DataSourceStrategy.scala:557)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:321)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3360)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2545)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2759)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) WARN  2020-06-01 03:44:27,010 com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler: /10.41.48.76:9042 replied with server error (Query response timeout of 60000, missing responses from nodes: [10.41.48.78]), defuncting connection.*
```

Comment: it is using solr predicate pushdown.. and netty has timeout of 60 secs.. even error shows 60 secs timeout

Comment: Yes. Where to change that 60 sec timeout for solr.

Comment: Or is there way to avoid SOLR while querying from Spark?

Comment: spark.sql.dse.search.enableOptimization can be set to false to disable solr pushdown